# How can I disable file download in Webdriver ChromeProfile

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I use Webdriver with Chromedriver on python.
I execute pages with automatic file downloading and I need to disable it.
What I need to set up in Chrome-driver download profile to disable automatic download?

Answer (score 3):

I found next solution:
in CromeOption I created a folder that can't be created ("NUL"), so file can't be downloaded, but I can check everything I need on a page.

```
chrome_profile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = {"download.default_directory": "NUL", "download.prompt_for_download": False, }
chrome_profile.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_profile)
```